# Is calling super's constructor redundant in this case?

Tags: java, class, super, sup

I always thought that when creating an object with a sub-class, we need to explicitly use `super(arguments list)` to call the constructor of the super class. However I did an experiment and realize that even **without** using the `super()`, the super class's constructor will be called automatically. Is this true?

If this is true, when is `super()` redundant and when it is not?

```
class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        System.out.println("Super Class");
    }           

}

class Child extends Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
        super();   //Is this redundant?
        System.out.println("Sub Class");
    }   
}

public class TestClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new Child();
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT** (**With** `super();` in Child Class):

```
Super Class
Sub Class
```

**OUTPUT** (**Without** `super();` in Child Class):

```
Super Class
Sub Class
```

Comment: super exist hidden even you don't call

Comment: You must call the super() constructor when you need to pass paramethers to it, otherwise if you do not call it, super() without parameters is implicitely called.

Comment: So we call explicitly when there are arguments in the constructor of the super class?

Answer (score 0):

By default `super()` is added in all sub-class so don't need to call it explicitly.

The default behavior can be overridden by calling overloaded constructor of super class using `super(args)` or overloaded constructor of same class using `this(args)`.

Suppose super class doesn't have no-argument constructor and you have created other constructor, in that case you have to call `super(args)` explicitly to resolve compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always consult [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7):

> If a constructor body does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation and the constructor being declared is not part of the primordial class Object, then the constructor body implicitly begins with a superclass constructor invocation "`super();`", an invocation of the constructor of its direct superclass that takes no arguments.